# com.android.internal.R cannot be resolved to a variable

Tags: android, android-resources

I'm trying to extend the RadioGroup class and I am attempting to duplicate the following constructor method:  RadioGroup(Context context, AttributeSet attr).

The problem is that I'm getting compile errors on the following parameters:

```
    com.android.internal.R.styleable.RadioGroup
    com.android.internal.R.attr.radioButtonStyle
    R.styleable.RadioGroup_checkedButton
    com.android.internal.R.styleable.RadioGroup_orientation
```

Here is the extended method:

```
    public AssistekRadioGroupColumns(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
            super(context, attrs);
            Resources res = Resources.getSystem();
            // retrieve selected radio button as requested by the user in the
            // XML layout file
            TypedArray attributes = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, com.android.internal.R.styleable.RadioGroup, com.android.internal.R.attr.radioButtonStyle, 0);



            int value = attributes.getResourceId(R.styleable.RadioGroup_checkedButton, View.NO_ID);
            if (value != View.NO_ID) {
                mCheckedId = value;
            }

            final int index = attributes.getInt(com.android.internal.R.styleable.RadioGroup_orientation, VERTICAL);
            setOrientation(index);

            attributes.recycle();
            init();
}
```

How can I get to these resources so I can extend the class?

The whole class (4.0) version can be seen [here](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.0.1_r1/android/widget/RadioGroup.java?av=f).

I tried to get the attributes through reflection, but this isn't quite working:

```
private int getAttribute(Context con) throws ClassNotFoundException, IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException { 
//use reflection to get styleable class.
Field[] alFields = null; 
int R_ID = 0;

for (Class<?> c : android.R.class.getClasses()) { 
     if (c.getName().indexOf("styleable") >= 0) { 
         alFields = Class.forName( con.getPackageName() + ".R$styleable" ).getFields();

     } 
 }
for (Field f : alFields) { 
    Log.d("field name",f.getName());
    if (f.getName().equals("RadioGroup_checkedButton")) { 
        int[] ret = (int[])f.get(null);
        R_ID = ret[0];
    }

}
return R_ID;


}

//gets all RadioGroup R,android.internal.styleable.RadioGroup values
private int[] getAttributes(Context con) throws IllegalAccessException, ClassNotFoundException { 
    //use reflection to get styleable class.
    Field[] alFields = null; 
    ArrayList<Integer> alInts = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    int[] ints = null;
    int count = 0;
    try {
        for (Class<?> c : android.R.class.getClasses()) { 
             if (c.getName().indexOf("styleable") >= 0) { 
                 //Log.d("get Class Name Outer", c.getName());
                //use reflection to access the resource class
                 alFields = Class.forName( con.getPackageName() + ".R$styleable" ).getFields();          
             } 

         }
         if (alFields != null) 
             {
                //Log.d("field numbers size", String.valueOf(alFields.length));                      
                for (Field field : alFields) { 

                 Class<?> targetType = field.getType();
                 //Log.d("field type", field.getType().toString());
                 if (targetType.equals(Integer.TYPE) && targetType.isPrimitive()) { 
                     Object objectValue = (Integer)field.getInt(null); 
                     alInts.add((Integer)objectValue);
                     count++;
                 }
                 ints = new int[count];
                 for (int i=0;i<alInts.size();i++) { 
                     ints[i] = alInts.get(i);
                 }
             }

         }
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (ClassNotFoundException e) { 
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return ints;


    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Class clasz = Class.forName("com.android.internal.R$styleable")
Field field = clasz.getDeclaredField("TextAppearance");
field.setAccessible(true);
int[] textAppearanceStyleArr = (int[])field.get(null);

field = clasz.getDeclaredField("TextAppearance_textSize");
field.setAccessible(true);
int textSizeStyle = (Integer)field.get(null);
```

Comment: Accessing internal APIs via reflection is not supported and may not work on all devices or in the future!

Answer (score 0):

The package com.android.internal is not present in the android.jar that every single developer uses.

However, you can get them by using the full framework.jar present on the android emulator or on a real device.

But be careful, most of the ressources or classes you will access will require your application to have root access.

You can found a good tutorial on how to use the framework.jar for your developments here : http://devmaze.wordpress.com/2011/01/18/using-com-android-internal-part-2-hacking-around/

Comment: What do you suggest for a workaround?   This application will be used worldwide and on many different types of devices so I don't think going the way you suggest will work.  Is there a jar I download somewhere and include it in my project?

Comment: The best workaround is to use this technique on a general android emulator. For instance : 4.0.3.
Then you could at least check on other versions of android if you development still work. This is just a symbolic link and it should work on most android version. Android sdk provides lots of emulator version to test on.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean "use this technique on a general android emulator".  What would I do?